# Is there a way to simplify a graph and still use the powers of the adjacency matrix to find the number of paths from once point to another?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I'm working on a little extra credit for a problem-solving course.

Jack is heading home from work on his bike. His home is 3 blocks north and 4 blocks to the east. The intersection one block north-east of him is broken so he doesn't want to ride there.

The question asks “How many ways are there for him to travel 5 blocks and still make it home if he only travels north and east?”

We solved this problem by counting and by raising the adjacency matrix to the ^5 power.

Graph: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1mPPcHSZO8As7OT7KmlbewhrubeKEad74

Matrix: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1mPPcHSZO8As7OT7KmlbewhrubeKEad74

We also covered the fact that the broken vertex can be removed without affecting the result.

This problem led to some discussion and now my professor is curious: Is it possible to reduce the size of this matrix further and still be able to find the number of paths by raising it to a power?

For example, if we combined paths with only one way home, we could have a  7 x 7 matrix instead of an 11 x 11 or 12 x 12.

Simplified graph: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1mPPcHSZO8As7OT7KmlbewhrubeKEad74

However, we need some way to represent the fact that by reducing the size of the matrix, we eliminated 4 vertices and 5 edges.

I know there's a way to assign weight to graphs, which would basically mean instead of a simple graph, we have vertices with more than one edge connecting them.

I don't think it's possible to do this, but perhaps someone knows why.

Regards